# get connected device in iphone setting Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, connection, core-bluetooth

I want to get a list of those that devices (peripheral) which I'm already connected to in my general iPhone bluetooth setting.

Trying Using Core bluetooth but not found way to it Is there any other possible way to find out Please help me out.

Comment: No, you can’t get connected peripherals. You can find connected audio devices via the AV framework

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Paulw11
 I am getting two different names for the same device.
1) Av connected port 
2) Core Bluetooth Scan for devics

Comment: Yes. You cannot correlate core Bluetooth devices with audio devices

Comment: @Paulw11 -  but the bluetooth device for which i am getting different names (via core bluetooth and Av connected port)is the Same Headphone.

Comment: Yes, but you cannot correlate core Bluetooth devices with audio devices. They are different frameworks and give different results. Core Bluetooth connects via BLE while the audio framework is using a legacy Bluetooth profile.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @paulw11's comments, your audio connection (BR/EDR) and your BLE connection (what Core Bluetooth sees) are independent connections. They do not have the same protocol. They do not have the same identifiers. And if they have the same name, that is only because the device manufacturer decided to make them the same (often they are intentionally different to reduce confusion).

AVAudioSessionRouteDescription gives you access to the current audio route, which may be a BR/EDR connection, or may be several other things. AVAudioSession provides extremely little control over the route, but you can see what it is (which I assume is what you're currently doing).

If your goal is to correlate the two connections, in order to know that a CBPeripheral and AVAudioSessionRouteDescription refer to the same device, this is a very difficult problem that requires cooperation with the device manufacturer. There is no general way to solve it. The device manufacturer needs to provide some mechanism to help you correlate.

There are extremely fragile ways to make this work without modifying the device firmware, but they depend on the specific features of the device you're working on. (I spent years building these kinds of solutions. Even working directly with the firmware developers, with full access to the source code, it is not a simple problem.) More details of your exact problem may help us provide a more specific answer.